# Making a div hidden and visible according to the chosen option under select tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code don't seem to work.
So i have a div like this:

```
<div class="abc">
<form>
**some input tags**
```

then this:

```
<select>
<option value="" onclick="myfx1()">yes</option>
<option value="" onclick="myfx2()">no</option></select>
```

And this is my js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfx1(){
    document.getElementById("hid").style.visibility="hidden";
}
function myfx2(){
    document.getElementById("hid").style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
```

***************and below is the div that has to appear when no is selected**********************

```
<div id="hid">
<select>
**some options**
</select>
<font>
**some text**
</font>
**some more textarea and input tags**
</div>
**end of the div**
```

then it ends with a button:

```
<input type="button" style="float:right" value="Go">
</div></form>
```

Comment: what is not working here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select onchange='myfx1(this.value)'>
<option value="1" >yes</option>
<option value="0" >no</option></select>


<script type="text/javascript">
function myfx1(value){
    if(value==1) {
    document.getElementById("hid").style.visibility="hidden";
}else {
document.getElementById("hid").style.visibility="visible";
}
}</script>
```

Comment: Its better to use `addEventListener` rather than inline events like `onclick` or `onchnage`. addEventListener won't override existing events and it has better separation of concerns.

Comment: yes u r right. but i am extending the code are done in question. it always better to give solution what is used in question. it's easy to understand for them.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<select name='options' id="select">
  <option value='yes'>Yes</option>
  <option value='no'>No</option>
</select>  

 <div id="hid">
   Test
</div>
```

JS

```
var elem = document.getElementById("hid");
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', function(){
  if(this.value == 'yes'){
   elem.style.visibility="visible";
 }else{
  elem.style.visibility="hidden";
 }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#YourSelectBoxID").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == "YourDesiredConditionForCheckWhichValueIsSelected") {
      $(".abc").hide();
   } else {
      $(".abc").show();
   }
});
```